# Background image for ios viewcontroller not working

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I need to set my background of viewcontroller to an image. AFTER reading other SO answers I see that we should put code:

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"login_page_bg.png"]]]
```

into `viewDidLoad`

I did this but still get white background. My login_page_bg.png is inside the same folder where my XYZLoginPageViewController.m is. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have any full screen subviews in that controller (scrollview, tableview)?

Answer (score 2):

Take imageview on view .

```
UIImageView *bgImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background-image"]];
bgImageView.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view addSubview:bgImageView];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:bgImageView];
```

Comment: that worked, thanks :) But why doesn't self.view setBackgroundColor work? I thought using a UIImageView would be unnecessarily adding an extra view to the scene.